Expo Unexpectedly Quits when saving .ts files on MacOs
As the title says. Has anyone else experienced this? I am using redux tool kit and redux-persist. It only crashes when saving files that end in .ts. These files are for redux and an API. I posted my package.json below. This is a bizarre issue and I can't find a fix.
{
  "name": "procecsmobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.13",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-expo-dev-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

